# US born kids with indian passport entring US with out US passport

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I am blessed with baby boy in US and I and my wife are Indian citizens. We wanted to apply Indian passport for my Kid as we are staying here in US temporarily as we will go back to India after couple of years. India does not allow dual citizenship so we can not apply US passport. How can my US born baby enter US with out US passport by Air? Birth certificate is acceptable?

Comment: Interesting situation. You cannot come by air with only a birth certificate. The airline will not allow. If you were coming from Canada or Mexico by road you could do it, or by private jet. However commercial airlines will not allow you to board. You will have to renounce US citizenship if he wants to get a visa to come because citizens cannot get visas. If you're able to get to the US airport **somehow** though, they will let him in because a US citizen cannot be turned away. Explore OCI, Overseas Citizen of India. https://www.in.ckgs.us/oci/

Answer (score 7):

It will be a problem for your child to travel to India and return to the US.

According to US law, anyone born in the US is a US citizen, and as such requires a US passport to enter the US by air.

Meanwhile, if Indian immigration sees he has no US visa and stamps in his Indian passport (and he cannot get a US visa as a US citizen), they will know he has another nationality too, with the following consequences.

So there are only two ways for your kid to travel to India and back to the US while you still live in the US:

1. (**recommended**): Get your baby a US passport and *overseas citizenship of India* (OCI). It's allowed to have both OCI and US citizenship, and OCI allows you to live in India permanently, but not vote or hold government positions. Furthermore, [it is easy for an OCI holder to get Indian citizenship back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_nationality_law#Citizenship_by_registration).
2. Get your baby an Indian passport, travel to and from the US through the Canadian or Mexican land border, and fly to/from Canada/Mexico. At the US land border, your child's US birth certificate can be used to enter the US.
   This way, you have to get a Canadian/Mexican double-entry transit visa in order to enter Canada/Mexico.

Comment: This is incorrect. Children can have dual citizenship from birth, and they lose their Indian citizenship only when they get a passport from the other country of citizenship. The child could get an Indian passport, but can't leave and return to the US in compliance with US law.  If the child never leaves and returns the US as a minor, however, he can get an Indian passport.

Comment: @DJClayworth Changed the answer

Comment: I have changed my vote.  You might also mention that reacquisition of Indian citizenship by registration is fairly easy for someone in this position.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_nationality_law#Citizenship_by_registration.

Comment: Another possibility might be going through US preclearance in Ireland or Abu Dhabi, though it will require getting visas to those countries with the Indian passport.

Comment: @phoog when you mention "this is incorrect" in your first comment, can you please elaborate which part of the OP was incorrect ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper the incorrect statements were "anyone possessing a foreign nationality loses Indian citizenship" and "your boy cannot get Indian citizenship unless he renounces his US citizenship."  In fact, the boy will have been a dual citizen until the acquisition of a US passport (if remember correctly; Indian nationality law was much fresher in my mind when I wrote that comment than it is now, nearly three years later, and it may be that the nationality is lost on application for the passport rather than on its acquisition).

Comment: @phoog Thanks for clarification, appreciate it. but I do not see those incorrect statements, in the OP ? or was OP edited after your clarification ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper you can see the revision history by clicking the link that says "edited" and the time of the last edit or, for this answer, at https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/93861/revisions.